# Dynamically create new Textviews in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

*I was unable to find any question on StackOverflow about this*:

I dynamically want to add `TextView` objects to a `ScrollView` (see XML layout) using Kotlin.

The simplified XML structure:

```xml
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/entry_list" />
</ScrollView>
```

What the app should look like after I execute the Kotlin:

```xml
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/entry_list" />
    <TextView android:text="Dynamically added text" />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

(note: The actual XML will not be changed in Runtime, this just describes what it should look like afterwards)

**How can I use Kotlin to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

I did some research on this, it is quite simple:

```kotlin
val dynamicTextview = TextView(this)

dynamicTextview.text = "Dynamically added text"

// add TextView to LinearLayout
entry_list.addView(dynamicTextview)
```

(note: you should import `TextView`, if you use *Android Studio*, it should prompt you to import that automatically)

Just add this code somewhere in the Activity you want to add the `TextView` to.

### References

- [A blogpost on *tutorialkart.com*](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-in-kotlin-android/) (not written by me)
- [Another post from *GeeksForGeeks*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-textview-in-kotlin/) (also not written by me)